# stuck on 400 bad request, method might be incorrect?

Tags: vue.js

Hello im currentenly stuck and im not quite sure whats wrong

my postman login is all fine but my backend dont accept anything so im pretty sure there is something wrong with my method

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
            error: null,
            login: {
                email: "",
                password: "",
                
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        UserLogin: function() {
            this.loading = true;

               this.axios.post('http://localhost:3000/login', {user: this.login}) 
                
                    .then((res) =>{
                    this.$cookies.set('jwt', res.data.jwt);
                    this.$cookies.set('isAdmin', res.data.isAdmin);
                    this.$router.push('/dashboard');
                   
                    }).catch(err => {
                        //fejl
                      this.error = err.response.data.message;
                    });
                    
                    this.loading = false;
            

        },
        
        CheckForNullInObject: function(obj) {
            for (let key in obj) {
                if(obj[key] == null || obj[key] == "") return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and my backend

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        res.status(400).json({ 
            message: "missing values1" 
        });
        return
    }
```

always hits the missing values1 no matter what I write

Answer (score 0):

You've `POST`ed the login data under `user`, but your backend code doesn't read that property.

Either update your frontend to send the data directly (without `user`):

```js
this.axios.post('http://localhost:3000/login', { ...this.login })
```

Or update the backend to read the data from `user`:

```js
if(!req.body.user.email || !req.body.user.password)
```

Comment: Thanks fixed the problem and the 503 I got after 
did not see the Little mistake there